# Can't get method to execute on parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to get a method to execute on a parent component when a button in one of its child components is clicked. I am using single file components with Webpack. Here's the code for the child component:

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="add">Click</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    add: () => {
      console.log('foo')
      this.$dispatch('addClick')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And the code for the parent:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <count :total="total"></count>
    <click></click>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import count from './components/count.vue'
import click from './components/click.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    count,
    click
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      total: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToTotal: () => {
      console.log('bar')
      this.total += 1
    }
  },
  events: {
    addClick: 'addToTotal'
  }
}
</script>
```

The `count` component is just an h1 element that displays the `total` variable. When I click the button, "foo" logs to the console, but "bar" does not and the total doesn't change. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using lambda notation, which is likely messing up your `this`. Try `function` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using lambda notation for your methods, which is giving them the wrong `this`. If you use `function` instead, it will work.

```js
Vue.component('click', {
  template: '#clicker',
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      console.log('foo')
      this.$dispatch('addClick')
    }
  }

})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      total: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToTotal: function () {
      console.log('bar')
      this.total += 1
    }
  },
  events: {
    addClick: 'addToTotal'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="clicker">
  <button v-on:click="add">Click</button>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <count :total="total"></count>
  <click></click>
  {{total}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two-way `.sync` binding type modifier on `total` property of `count` component so that the value will be updated when parent `total` value is changed. Here is an example:

```js
Vue.component('click', {
    template: '<button v-on:click="add">Click</button>',
    methods: {
        add: function () {
            this.$dispatch('addClick');
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('count', {
    template: '<h1 v-text="total"></h1>',
    props: {
        total: {
            type: Number,
            twoWay: true
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        total: 1
    },
    methods: {
        addTotal: function () {
            this.total++;
        }
    },
    events: {
        addClick: 'addTotal'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.25/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <count :total.sync="total"></count>
    <click></click>
</div>
```